# Reporting Services Built in 2012 Deploy in 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have been working for a client who run SQL Server 2008 in their live environment. I had been working onsite for a period but now work from home. However, due to security, I cannot connect to the live setup, I can only connect to a test server. This server runs SQL Server 2012. I script any code and send it to the office for someone to deploy. The problem I have is I am now doing some reporting services work. They are only pretty basic reports, tablix controls, nothing fancy. Is is possible to build on 2012 and deploy to 2008? Can I do something with the .rdl file to make this work or is it not going to be feasible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Their test server operates in a completely different environment than their production server? Wow... On the plus side, it means they actually have two test servers and to avoid confusion between the two they call one "live".

Comment: Chris, this particular test server is for my purposes only as I am an external contractor so I have no access to any other servers, hence it being completely isolated from the live server. There are only two servers, live and this test one.

Comment: I think Chris's point is that you should set up the test server to match the live server as closely as possible. Having different major version numbers of software doesn't qualify as a test server. But all of that aside, your question of "Can I take a 2012 .rdl and deploy to 2008"?" is a valid one. (But I'm pretty sure the answer is that this isn't an easy transition.)

Answer (score 3):

In the Properties of the ReportServer Project in Visual Studio you can set the target server version.

Right click the Project in the Solution Explorer pane and set the TargetServerVersion Property to the required version. This works for reports SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 onwards. The designer will then manage what features are available to avoid using features from a later version of SSRS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The .rdl files are nicely formated XML. You can use your favorite diff tool to compare reports generated in either version of the tool.

I'm pretty sure  that Microsoft doesn't support moving a newer RDL to an older version server.

There were huge changes to the .rdl format between 2005 and 2008, moderate changes between 2008 and 2008R2, but I haven't really looked into 2008R2 versus 2012. From what I've seen these should be smaller changes yet.

If you do this you are off of the golden supported brick road. Since this server is production, and you don't have a good way to test this, I would find a 2008 server to develop with. I wouldn't want my name connected with the possible problems that could come up with a hack to move the rdl backwards.